# Vegas Pro Chroma Key not working properly

Tags: vegas-pro, greenscreen, chromakey

After I start doing chroma key with the following image
[image]

With black blackground it gets well

[image]

But when I try to make the background white

[image]

After I tune it, it starts to be blue

[image]

What am I doing wrong?